# Python crontab try except ValueError

Tags: python, linux, try-catch, pymssql

I've got this script than when I run from command line it works fine...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
from time import sleep
import os
import logging
import glob
import sys
import subprocess
import pymssql
import shutil
import StringIO
from StringIO import StringIO

#Check share mounted
if os.path.ismount("/home/marco/cas01-share/") == 0:

    #logging.info('share not mounted')
    print "share not mounted"
    #mount share
    #logging.info('share now mounted')
    #print "share now mounted"
else:
    print "share mounted"

# File paths
fullpath2Newfile = "/home/marco/cas01-share/New/"
fullpathfiles2Process = "/home/marco/cas01-share/Process/"
fullpathProcessedfiles = "/home/marco/cas01-share/Processed/"

if not os.listdir('/home/marco/cas01-share/New'):
    print "directory empty"
else:
    print "directory not empty"

    # Directory more than one file?
    num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir('/home/marco/cas01-share/New')
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('/home/marco/cas01-share/New', f))])
    print "directory has " + str(num_files) + " files"



    num_files = 0

    for filename in os.listdir('/home/marco/cas01-share/New'):
        succesfullRun = 0
        num_files += 1

        print filename
        filename = str(filename)
        batchnumber = filename.strip("['SENSE-extract-ascii--.csv']")[:-9]
        print batchnumber

        newfullpath2Newfile = fullpath2Newfile + filename
        fullpathfiles2Process = "/home/marco/cas01-share/Process/SENSE-extract.csv"
        fullpathProcessedfiles = "/home/marco/cas01-share/Processed/SENSE-extract-" + batchnumber + ".csv"
        print newfullpath2Newfile
        print fullpathfiles2Process
        print fullpathProcessedfiles


        # Execute job
        ExceptionFlag = 0
        while (succesfullRun == 0):

            if ExceptionFlag == 0:
                shutil.move(newfullpath2Newfile, fullpathfiles2Process)

            try:

                # Move to sense check folder
                # Connect to DB
                conn = pymssql.connect(server='IP', user='User', password='password', tds_version='8.0')
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.execute("EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'Marco_test'")

            except Exception as e:
                (error_code, error_message) = e

                ExceptionFlag = 1

                #print error_message

                if "does not exist" in error_message:
                    print "ERROR: Job name not found"

                if "job is already running" in error_message:
                    print "ERROR: a Job is already running"

                if "job already has a pending request" in error_message:
                    print "ERROR: pending request"

                time.sleep(0.5)

            else:
                print "Job executed succesfully"
                # Copy file to processed
                shutil.copy(fullpathfiles2Process, fullpathProcessedfiles)

                succesfullRun = 1

            conn.close()
            time.sleep(0.5)

exit()
```

But when I try to schedule on crontab I get the bellow error

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

#SENSE
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/administrator/Share/scripts/python3 >> /home/administrator/Share/scripts/logs/sense$
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "...", line 239, in 
>       (error_code, error_message) = e ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

I think its to do with there's no pipeline between the "cronos schedule executed job" and the script it self, I dont know if that makes any sense, like it doesnt know where to get the information from and viceversa...

In essence in trying to catch an exceptions of an EXECUT a MSSQL JOB command.

Comment: Just replace that line with `print(e)` to see what the error is.  It might be something that you weren't expecting.  Once you fix that bug, you should change `except Exception ...` to `except WhateverYouExpect ...` so that unknown errors do not pass silently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated and working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
from time import sleep
import os
import logging
import glob
import sys
import subprocess
import pymssql
import shutil
import StringIO
from StringIO import StringIO
import mechanize
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

#Configure logging
if os.path.isdir("/home/administrator/Share/scripts/logs/") == 0:
    os.makedirs("/home/administrator/Share/scripts/logs/")

if os.path.isfile("/home/administrator/Share/scripts/logs/sense.log") == 0:
    open("/home/administrator/Share/scripts/logs/sense.log", 'w')

logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/administrator/Share/scripts/logs/sense.log',level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
logging.info('RUNNING SCRIPT')

#Check share mounted
if os.path.ismount("/home/administrator/-share/") == 0:

    logging.info('share not mounted')
    #print "share not mounted"
    #mount share
    os.popen("sudo mount -t cifs \"//path to network share -o username=username,domain=domain,sec=ntlmssp,password=password")
    logging.info('share now mounted')
    #print "share now mounted"

# start Automated browsing
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open("page")
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
browser.form['email'] = "user"
browser.form['password'] = "pass"
browser.submit()

#Open Page (Data)
browser.follow_link(text="Data")

#Find generate button
i = 0
batch = 0
for form in browser.forms():

    browser.form = list(browser.forms())[0]  # use when form is unnamed

    for control in browser.form.controls:
        if control.name == "generate":
            batch = 1
            logging.info('generate detected')
            #print "generate detected"
            #Click button
            browser.submit(nr=i)

    if batch == 0:
        logging.info('nothing to generate')
        #print "nothing to generate"
        #print "*******************"

    i =+ 1
#END Find generate button

#Back to "admin/Dowload" page (Data)
browser.follow_link(text="Data")

# Data Table parsing
html = browser.response().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find("table")

i = 0
for row in table.findAll("tr")[1:]:

    col = row.findAll("td")

    if not col:
        break

    batch = str(col[0])
    records = col[1]
    generated = col[2]
    downloaded = col[3]
    links = col[4]
    photos = col[5]
    sheet = str(col[6])
    confirmed = col[7]

    if "Not yet downloaded" in confirmed:
        i += 1

        stripbatch = batch.strip("<td></td>")
        stripsheet = sheet.strip("<td><a href=\"download/xls/\">Excel</a></td>")

        url = "website" + stripsheet
        time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        file = "/home/administrator/-share/New/SENSE-extract-ascii-" + stripsheet + "-" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d") + ".csv"

        #Dowload file
        logging.info('File %s Downloaded', stripsheet)
        #print "File " + stripsheet + " Downloaded"
        browser.retrieve(url, file)[0]

    if i < 1:
        logging.info('nothing to dowload')
        #print "nothing to dowload"
        #print "******************"
        break

#END Table parsing

#Reparse table to confirm
browser.follow_link(text="Data") #reload page to see changes

html = browser.response().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find("table")

browser.select_form(nr = 0)

i=1
while i >= 1:

    browser.follow_link(text="Data") #reload page to see changes

    html = browser.response().read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find("table")
    browser.select_form(nr = 0)

    for form in browser.forms():

        for control in browser.form.controls:
            if control.type == "submit":
                i += 1
            else:
                i = 0

    if i == 0:
        logging.info('nothing to confirm')
        #print "nothing to confirm"
        #print "******************"
    else:
        logging.info('%s confirmed', control.name[0])
        #print control.name[0] + "confirmed"

    browser.submit(nr = 0)

logging.info('*** Batch generated and CSV file downloaded from Sense ***')
#print "*** done ***"

#END reparsin table to confirm

#Change mount for access to test, for NEW, processed ...
# Declase File paths

# Scrap file information for naming Naming

# Move and replace from New to sense processed folder

#Execute Job start by job_name

# Copy file to processed


#END Sense file downloading


# File paths
fullpath2Newfile = "/home/administrator/-share/New/"
fullpathfiles2Process = "/home/administrator/-share/"
fullpathProcessedfiles = "/home/administrator/-share/Processed/"

if not os.listdir('/home/administrator/cas01-share/New'):
    # print "directory empty"
        logging.info('No New files to upload')

else:
    #print "directory not empty"

    # Directory more than one file?
    num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir('/home/administrator/-share/New')
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('/home/administrator/-share/New', f))])
    #print "directory has " + str(num_files) + " files"

    # logging.info('More than one file in New Directory')
    logging.info('Directory has: %s Files', str(num_files))



    num_files = 0

    for filename in os.listdir('/home/administrator/-share/New'):
        succesfullRun = 0
        num_files += 1

        # print filename
        logging.info('File: %s', filename)

        filename = str(filename)
        batchnumber = filename.strip("['SENSE-extract-ascii--.csv']")[:-9]
        print batchnumber

        newfullpath2Newfile = fullpath2Newfile + filename
        fullpathfiles2Process = "/home/administrator/-share/SENSE-extract.csv"
        fullpathProcessedfiles = "/home/administrator/-share/Processed/SENSE-extract-" + batchnumber + ".csv"
        print newfullpath2Newfile
        # print fullpathfiles2Process
        # print fullpathProcessedfiles


        # Execute job
        ExceptionFlag = 0
        while (succesfullRun == 0):

            if ExceptionFlag == 0:
                shutil.move(newfullpath2Newfile, fullpathfiles2Process)

            try:

                # Move to sense check folder
                # Connect to DB
                conn = pymssql.connect(server='server', user='domain\user', password='pwd', tds_version='8.0')
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.execute("EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'jobname'")

            except Exception as e:
                (error_message) = e
                #print(e)

                ExceptionFlag = 1

                print error_message
                #print error_message


                if "does not exist" in error_message:
                    # print "ERROR: Job name not found"
                    logging.info('ERROR: Job name not found')

                if "job is already running" in error_message:
                     #print "ERROR: a Job is already running"
                    logging.info('ERROR: a Job is already running')

                if "job already has a pending request" in error_message:
                    # print "ERROR: pending request"
                    logging.info('ERROR: pending request')

                if "Unable to connect" in error_message:
                    # print "ERROR: Server unavailable"
                    logging.info('ERROR: Server unavailable')

                time.sleep(0.5)


            else:
                # print "Job executed succesfully"
                logging.info('Job %s Executed', batchnumber)
                # Copy file to processed
                shutil.copy(fullpathfiles2Process, fullpathProcessedfiles)

                succesfullRun = 1

            #conn.close()
            time.sleep(0.5)


logging.info('Finished uploading jobs')
logging.info('END')
exit()

#END script
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are unpacking an Exception. Exceptions should not be assumed to be iterables, nor should you assume they contain arguments.

```
In [2]: try:
   ...:     assert False
   ...: except Exception as e:
   ...:     c, m = e
   ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2e0dd0160822> in <module>()
      2     assert False
      3 except Exception as e:
----> 4     c, m = e
      5 

ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

If you pass a message to the Exception class, it then has 1 value:

```
In [3]: try:
    assert False, "This is a message"
except Exception as e:
    c, m = e
   ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-8af2ea044375> in <module>()
      2     assert False, "This is a message"
      3 except Exception as e:
----> 4     c, m = e
      5 

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Your error handling **inherently** produces an error after your error catching. Learn to use traceback or `Exception.args` instead:

**Traceback Example**

```
In [10]: try:
   ....:         assert False, "This is a message"
   ....: except Exception as error:
   ....:     trace = traceback.format_exc()
   ....:     print(trace, file=sys.stderr)
   ....:     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-10-5a56c0f9112a>", line 2, in <module>
    assert False, "This is a message"
AssertionError: This is a message
```

**Exception.args Example**

```
In [11]: from __future__ import print_function

In [12]: import sys

In [13]: try:
   ....:        assert False, "This is a message"
   ....: except Exception as error:
   ....:        print(error.args, file=sys.stderr)
   ....:     
('This is a message',)
```

Comment: you mean this `(error_code, error_message) = e` is producing and error? the strange thing is that is working fine from another server... is have a look at traceback and exceptions

Comment: It's possible you have multiple arguments @maco1717 from another server. Or the error is not raised from another server. It doesn't solve your full problem, but it solves the question asked by you.

Either, the arguments are different, raising a different class of exceptions from your new server, or your errors were never raised in your old case so that block was never executed. Either way, that line is bad.

Comment: @maco1717, Ultimately I can't fully debug your code, but I can recommend logging the full error traceback so you know what you're working with. I do also know removing that line of code will go a little ways.

Comment: I'm suspecting is a case of the error is not raised from the other server, I think the connection is not being established, I have to research whats going on exactly, I got to this line from another post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809872/stdout-pymssql-to-variable) I think @zondo was right about not picking up the exception, at least I hope that's the solution

Comment: `OSError` exceptions usually have err_code and err_message  in the `args` and it is common to extract them from the excpetion into an error message to be printed or logged. Maybe you saw a code doing that.

Comment: @VPfB, a quick check over the pymssql test cases shows that only two exception cases are defined, and they never unpack them like OSErrors. There's also the possibility of other errors occurring as well... The Driver exception is raised with only 1 str argument, and the Database error with a single connection argument. Neither should work with unpacking. You wouldn't expect an OSError (typically) in an SQL connection.

https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/blob/ec46feae57b6c83cbee0615aef407a46ecfd650b/src/_mssql.pyx#L146

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh: I did not expect an OSError. Not at all. I'm sorry if my comment was not clear enough. I just tried to say that: (1) err_code and err_msg can be found in OSError exceptions (in the args attribute), and (2) I guess that the error mentioned in the very first comment was caused by some OSError exception handling code that was incorrectly and errornously "reused" for non-OSError exceptions.

Comment: @VPfB Ah fair. Either way it's code that should be removed, but it's understandable. Thanks,

Comment: Afther a while wasnt able to replicate issue and it working, i going to put the final code on a answer posted.

Comment: about the line `(error_code, error_message) = e`causing the error. I'm using now `(error_message) = e` as you can see from the code posted, and this is working find. so I dont know what kind of error this is returning, using or what else, but it's working for now. thanks

Comment: @maco1717 Still not safe (although in this case it will be safe for pymssql errors). You should explicitly state `message = error.args`, or do a full traceback.

Comment: Thanks for the support, I'll have a look in to traceback and exceptions.

Comment: @maco1717 Of course. See my original post for fully working examples to print error logs to a log, or to stdout (the console).

Comment: Thanks I'm going to have to read a bit to be able to understand that post to be honest, dont  completly understand what's going on... like the in operator never seen that before, gonna have to learn that aswell...